# Laravel - Intervention image stop my cron job

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

i have a cron command where in handle i have:

```
/**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $url = "https://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/65185616_1653683748.jpg";
        dd("My code arrive here.");
        $img = Image::make($url);
        dd("My code doesn't arrive here");
    }
```

my code is stoping when arrive to "`$img = Image::make($url);`" i don't know why, maybe because this method has a return ?

```
public static function make($data)
    {
        return self::getManager()->make($data);
    }
}
```

i have another cron job that works well, i don't understand why.

Comment: That's what `dd()` does. It **stops execution** and dumps out the arguments you passed it. If you want to see information but not stop execution, use `Log::info('My code arrives here.')` or something.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was the size of image, this image https://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/65185616_1653683748.jpg have 16MB about. I tried with a small image and it works.